# Need help optimizing a site for speed and response time

Tags: 6, proxies, caching

In my Drupal 6 site (fairly busy about 200 anonymous users on average at at time) I have the following setup to speed up the site.

- Caching Mode - normal
- Optimize JavaScript files
- Gzip enabled via .htaccess
- Cloudflare - normal setting
- Disabled database logging

Can I add memcached or Varnish into this setup? Which one will work better for this site? Should I even care about Varnish and memcached in this setup?

Comment: Whether Varnish or memcache will be worthwhile or not requires profiling your website.  There are other things that should be done before throwing caching at a site to ensure optimal performance.

Comment: What is a typical response time? What type of hosting do you have?

Comment: Hi the response time is quite good but I want to setup the server so it's at its fastest. Hosting is AWS EC2 server with AWS RDS for mysql dbase..

Answer (score 2):

You can use both as per my knowledge.

For Drupal generally, Varnish works for unauthenticated users traffic and memcached will cache authenticated users traffic.

Memcache saves your DB from doing a lot of read work, Varnish saves your dynamic web server from CPU load by making you generate pages less frequently.

But in your case I think Varnish is better option.

Comment: Use both, but if I had to pick one I'd go for memcache actually.

Comment: Hi Mikeytown why do you recommend memcache only? Thanks

Comment: @user3236765 Use both if you can. Memcache can be used for the page cache which varnish only does so there is a slight overlap.

Comment: Hi with all the schemes I've enabled as per my original question memcache will work?